# Cannot synchronize my project in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, svn, azure, git-svn

My team and I started a project at Azure and we have a git as the VCS/SCM.

One of my partners had made a few changes, and he had commited them. When I try to get those changes at my local repository, and I press sync at the Visual Studio, the following message appears

> Cannot merge because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo
>   your changes before merging again. See the Output window for details.

The output window shows the message below

> Cannot complete the operation because of existing changes to the
>   following file:`Project\Project.csproj`

I have searched everywhere at google, but I did not find anything similar.

Can anyone help me with this?

We are stack.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What operation are you attempting? Merge or Update? You should be running SVN Update.

Comment: "git as the SVN" makes no sense. git & SVN are 2 separate distinct version control systems. You can use git locally and synchronize with an SVN server, but the two aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

It probably means VisualStudio automatically added some references to the file ProjectProject.csproj, where it keeps general project settings. In VisualStudio 2013 you may do:

1. Go to the TeamExplorer
2. Select "Changes"
3. Search through Included and Excluded Changes, .csproj file is probably there
4. Right click on it and select compare with unchanged to see the differences
5. Now choose to commit it or undo the changes (if, for example, the changes are not necessary) to be able to sync with the current repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same dilemma and it turned out that somehow the file that was preventing me from switching branches and was in my solution, was not being tracked like the other files were. I just added it to source control via the explorer window, committed and pushed it, then I was able to switch branches just fine. Hope this helps.